# Update line in database

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm developping an application with c# and ADO .NET entity data model. I have a table Articles(idArticle, nameArticle, statusArticles). I want to retrieve the first article where statusArticle=false, and update her value to true. Someone can help me with this code please:

```
   private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
            {
               Articles firstArticle = db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusArticle == false);
                if (firstArticle != null)
                {
                    firstArticle.statusArticle = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Article validated", "OK");
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you getting any exception here..

Comment: no error, but the value is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as follows

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
        {
           Articles firstArticle = db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusArticle == false);
           // firstArticle is not null anyways as you are calling FirstOrDefault()
         **EDIT** // In case nothing has status = false, you will get a new Articles object, so instead of the below null check, you have to check for other property like id or name that will be unique.
            if (firstArticle != null)
            {
                firstArticle.statusArticle = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Article validated", "OK");
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi: I have updated the post with the comment, instead of checking for null, you should check for any other unique property or 1) you should update the articles based on the input id. This will be a right approach.

Comment: @HennyH you said that firstArticle is not null anyways, what if there isn't any article with statusArticle=0? what would happen?

Comment: @HennyH ok thank you for information, i will try to study this. I have another problem, i want that the form will be refreshed after the button click so i can interact with next article, but the form is not refreshed, i tried several codes exept the one of application.restart that is heavy!  do you have an idea about refreshing at the boutton click  without application restart?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi I updated my answer yet again, should be more clear, hopefully it fully answers your original question. I recommend posting that as a separate question regarding the refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

`.FirstOrDefault()`

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source //db.Articles
)
```

will return:

> default(TSource) if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in source.

**default(TSource)**  returns `null` for reference type elements or (usually) `0` for value type elements.

Your amended code:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
            {
               Articles firstArticle = db.Articles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.statusArticle == false);
                if (firstArticle != null)
                {
                    firstArticle.statusArticle = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Article validated", "OK");
                    db.SaveChanges(); //change (can go before/after validation message)
                    this.Refresh();

                }
            }
        }
```